# OR statement in USERELATIONSHIP

Tags: dax

I am writing this wrong code here but you can clearly see the logic what I am trying to do here. I just want DAX to understand to execute either USERELATIONSHIP('VOLUME FACT'[Provider Index], 'Account Type DIM'[id]) or USERELATIONSHIP('VOLUME FACT'[Follower Index], 'Account Type DIM'[id]).
Following is the complete incorrect code

CALCULATE(
CALCULATE(
SUM('VOLUME FACT'[manual_opened_usd_volume]),
USERELATIONSHIP('VOLUME FACT'[Manual Open Volume Index], 'Volume Type DIM'[Index])
),
OR(
USERELATIONSHIP('VOLUME FACT'[Provider Index], 'Account Type DIM'[id]),
USERELATIONSHIP('VOLUME FACT'[Follower Index], 'Account Type DIM'[id])
)
)

this gives an error that USERELATIONSHIP can only be used in a calculate statement which I already know. But I am not sure how to make this code work

Comment: I absolutely can't "clearly see" what you are trying to do here. What are you trying to accomplish? Show your data, your data model and relations, and the desired outcome.

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/USERELATIONSHIP-complex-case/m-p/3149186#M112763

please read this. I have explained in detail what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think you got your data model wrong. In a good model, there is never a need for multiple relations between dim and fact. Make volume type an attribute in a dimension, then the desired  result will be simply a sum of all volume types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RADO, I will try this out. Also, The data model that I shared is just a small part of a complex data model. When you have such big data models there is will be cases when you have to create inactive relationships ( You cannot avoid them, unless you keep on creating copies of dimension tables), especially when you have transaction data in fact table where you have multiple date columns. And hence the need and reason for creating USERELATIONSHIP function in DAX.

Comment: Creating copies of dimensional tables is a much better solution than creating inactive relations. You lose a bit of memory, but gain more optimal performance, conceptual clarity and much simpler DAX.